# Structure of the $\omega$-limit set

Tags: calculus, limits, dynamical-systems

In the book Hale, J.K.: Asymptotic Behavior of Dissipative Systems (2007), in Chapter $1$, page $1 $, it says:

"The $\omega$-limit set of $U$ is defined as $\omega(U) = \bigcap_{n \geq 0} \overline{\bigcup_{k \geq n} T^k(U) }$. In particular, the set $\omega(U)$ consists of all of the limit points of the orbit of $U$. However, $\omega(U)$ is generally much larger than this latter set."

I don't understand what else can be in $\omega(U)$, besides the limit points of orbits. How to visualise it? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Are you sure this is reproduced correctly? "all of the limit points of the orbit of $U$", it would make more sense as "all of the limit points of the orbits of $U$", that is "all orbits to points in $U$", or $ω(U)$ can be large than $\bigcup_{u\in U}ω(u)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example $\omega(U)$ contains the limit of every convergent sequence of limit points of orbits (since it is closed), which might not be a limit point itself.

For instance, if you consider the identity map $T(x)=x$ then trivially $\omega(U)=\overline{U}$ but the set of limit points is just $U$.

Comment: So not just the limits of convergent sub-sequences $T^{n_k}(u)$, $u\in U$, but also of convergent sub-sequences with moving basis points, $T^{n_k}(u_k)$, $u_k\in U$.